# Making a multiplication table of type int array array in OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I'm studying some basics of OCaml's imperative programming.

I'm trying to make a simple int array array where it contains the multiplication table up to the integer I pass as argument.

For example the output of `table 2`is expected to return

> [|[|1;2|];[|2;4|]|]

My code doesn't work. I first initialize an array with enough space and fill it with zeros. The iteration for `x` works for the indexing of the array because every entry of the array gets filled but something is wrong with the `(x+1) * (y+1)` part.

The outcome of `table 2` is `[|[|2;4|];[|2;4|]|]`, as if it's not iterating properly through x.

The provided answer works. I have no idea why-- since it seems that we're doing exactly the same thing. We initialize an array with enough space and fill it with zero. And then we use nested for loops to fill it. Is it because of the first for loop the answer uses? Why though?

My code:

```
let table n =
    let a = Array.make n (Array.make n 0) in
    for x = 0 to n-1 do   
        for y = 0 to n-1 do   
            a.(x).(y) <- ((x+1) * (y+1));
        done;
    done;
    a;;
```

The answer:

```
let table n =
    let a = Array.make n [||] in
    for x = 0 to n-1 do
        a.(x) <- Array.make n 0
    done;
    for y = 0 to n-1 do
        for x = 0 to n-1 do
            a.(x).(y) <- (x+1)*(y+1)
        done
    done;
    a;;
```

Comment: The expression `Array.make n 0` creates a single array. Then when that value is passed to `Array.make n (...)`, instead of creating `n` copies of that value, like you are expecting, it will simply make each of it's cells point to the value it was given. Thus you will have `2` Arrays in memory, instead of `n+1` Arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `Array.make` is going to fill the array with the same single value. So, your outer array contains not `n` different arrays, but `n` references to the same array.

You would get the same undesired result with the following code:

```
let aa = Array.make n 0 in
let a = Array.make n [||] in
for x = 0 to n - 1 do
    a.(x) <- aa
done
```

The working example is written to avoid this problem. First it creates an outer array containing `n` copies of the null array `[||]`, then it fills it in with `n` *different* array objects by calling `Array.make` for each one.

To adapt your code, you can use `Array.init` instead, which calls a specified function for each different array element:

```
let a = Array.init n (fun _ -> Array.make n 0)
```

Or you can use `Array.make_matrix`:

```
let a = Array.make_matrix n n 0
```

**Update**

Using `ref 5` instead of `0` in the example doesn't really change anything except that `ref 5` is itself mutable. Assume we're not going to modify the reference, but just change the contents of the inner array. Then you see something like this:

```
# let a = Array.make 3 (Array.make 3 (ref 5));;
val a : int ref array array =
  [|[|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 5}|];
    [|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 5}|];
    [|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 5}|]|]
# a.(1).(2) <- ref 88;;
- : unit = ()
# a;;
- : int ref array array =
[|[|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 88}|];
  [|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 88}|];
  [|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 88}|]|]
```

As you can see, all the inner arrays seem to change. That's because there's only one inner array. So really just one array has changed. The outer array contains this one array in all 3 of its elements.

Next, note that there's just one call to `ref 5`. This means that all the references (all 9 of them) are the same reference. You can see this in the following:

```
# let a = Array.make 3 (Array.make 3 (ref 5));;
val a : int ref array array =
  [|[|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 5}|];
    [|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 5}|];
    [|{contents = 5}; {contents = 5}; {contents = 5}|]|]
# a.(1).(2) := 99;;
- : unit = ()
# a;;
- : int ref array array =
[|[|{contents = 99}; {contents = 99}; {contents = 99}|];
  [|{contents = 99}; {contents = 99}; {contents = 99}|];
  [|{contents = 99}; {contents = 99}; {contents = 99}|]|]
```

As expected, all of the elements changed to 99, because there's only one reference that shows up in all 9 spots.

If you have other example bits of code that you'd like to have explained, you could add them above. If they're complicated it might be better to post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand that Array.make n 0 creates one array and I am passing that same reference to a single array into my outer array n times. 
Why doesn't this same logic extend to Array.make n (ref 5)? Unlike the example with Array.make it seems it creates separate references to ref 5 such that if I change one element in the outer array it doesn't affect the other elements. 
(I am aware that I can do let x = ref 5 in Array.make n (x))

Comment: `Array.make n (ref 5)` indeed creates an array with `n` copies of just one reference. It just adds more complexity because both the array and the reference are mutable. So you have to keep track of more things in your head. I'll update my answer to show the behavior of this case (assuming I understand what case you mean).